# Optimization of pixel iteration by multiple goroutines

Tags: go, image-processing, optimization, concurrency, goroutine

I created a function that lets you iterate concurrently over a given image and allows you to read the `x`, `y` position and read/replace a given `color.Color` pixel. I find it very easy and pleasant to use such an API, where we pass only the target image and a *delegate* to the function. All the logic involved in calling goroutines is hidden and you can focus on implementing the specific functionality.

The performed profiling showed that the function is much faster than the classic approach (without additional goroutines), but it also shows a large number of allocations, and I am not sure what in this function , "failed".

- Is the problem caused by frequent calls to anonymous functions which results in allocations on the stack?
- Is the prolem caused by using `image.Image` and `color.Color` abstractions which results in the need to call additional logic to decide which color space we are dealing with (RGBA/NRGBA/YCbCr etc.)?
- Shouldn't `channel`'s be used instead of primitive types in the passed delegate function?

Or is there some other fundamental problem in this code that I am not seeing?

Code:

```golang
type ReadWriteAccess = func(xIndex, yIndex int, color color.Color) color.Color

func ParallelRowReadWrite(i draw.Image, a ReadWriteAccess) {
    width := i.Bounds().Dx()
    height := i.Bounds().Dy()

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(height)

    for y := 0; y < height; y += 1 {
        go func(yIndex int) {
            defer wg.Done()

            for xIndex := 0; xIndex < width; xIndex += 1 {
                originalColor := i.At(xIndex, yIndex)
                modifiedColor := a(xIndex, yIndex, originalColor)

                i.Set(xIndex, yIndex, modifiedColor)
            }
        }(y)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Edit (Benchmark results added):

Memory benchmark result:
[image]

CPU benchmark result:
[image]

Comment: Just lookup where the allocations happens, e.g. via running the benchmarks with -memprofile mem.out and inspect it via pprof. No need to guess or ask if you can measure.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Don't use sync.WaitGroup values (use pointer).

Comment: I have attached screenshots of the profiling benchmark results. The WaitGroup issue is that the anonymous functions called in separate goroutine should access the WaitGroup via a pointer passed as the param or is it a matter of creating a new instance as a pointer (e.g.: via new())?

Comment: `wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}` or `wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)`.

Comment: You see that `*NRGBA.At` is (solely) responsible for the memory allocations. There is no easy solution if you want to work in generic color models.